# How to require all files in a directory, in a gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I know that I can require all files in a directory using

```
Dir['path/to/files/**/*.rb'].each { |file| require file }
```

However, I'm trying to do that for a gem setup file, like so:

```
class MyGem
  module NS; end
end

Dir['lib/my_gem/files/**/*.rb'].each { |file| require file }
```

(where all the files in `lib/my_gem/files` are namespaced under MyGem::NS). With a directory structure that looks like this:

```
lib                              
|-- my_gem                        
|   |-- files              
|   |   |-- file1.rb       
|   |   |-- file2.rb         
|   |   |-- file3.rb         
|   |   `-- ... (many more)      
`-- my_gem.rb                     
my_gem.gemspec
```

And, well, the `Dir` command doesn't seem to work when I require my gem in another file, since it seems to look for the file paths at run time in my project root (of whatever project I've required my gem from).

How can I require all the files in `lib/my_gem/files` in `lib/my_gem.rb`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Rubygems has a facility called [find_files](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/5818e9d7fadebd6237f71c5c19539e996cc58df0/lib/rubygems.rb#L455-485) that will allow you to search based anything in the load path:

```
Gem.find_files("my_gem/files/**/*.rb").each { |path| require path }
```

Comment: This finds all rb files and not only main files, like with each gem you have to have single require statement to include that gem in app, you dont need to require all the files one by one but a single one

Comment: This also finds the files in spec directory. In my case, `Gem.find_files('mygem/folder/*.rb')` results in `--/mygem/lib/mygem/folder/xxx.rb` and `--/mygem/spec/mygem/folder/xxx_spec.rb`. Sure we `.reject` spec files but is there a better way?

Answer (score -1):

You can do a recursive search using *find* and then run through the response list and include them line by line.

Something like

```
`find #{root_path}/lib/my_gem/files/**/*.rb`.split("\n").each { |p| require p }
```

Comment: This wouldn't be a cross-platform approach.